# How do i return a text statement as well as a function output in the same return statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I am trying to understand how I can return 'multiple discounts' as well as this.redeemDisc all within `if (count > 1)`

```
`if (count > 1) {
    //return 'multiple discounts';
    return this.redeemDisc(
      {
        //BusinessId: BusinessId,
        discountId: offer.id,
        userUuid: userUuid,
        code: code,
        locationId: locationId
      }).then(redeemed => {
        return redeemed;
      }
      )
  }`
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you give me the response of `this.redeemDisc`?

Comment: The postman response is

    `"redeemed": {
        "createdAt": "2019-11-01T22:23:17.168Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-11-01T22:23:17.168Z",
        "id": "33ba42f0-fcf6-11e9-824d-ede07167778c",
        "UserUuid": "b136ccd9-0783-482d-956b-7082286051b3",
        "DiscountId": "91c0a250-fc1e-11e9-ac4a-e93a04a07c14",
        "BusinessId": "60b7c080-b88f-11e9-932c-e5ea93cc8e76",
        "locationId": "66743120-fc1e-11e9-ac4a-e93a04a07c14"`

Comment: I need more context... `redeemDisc` seems to return data of just one disc... do you have a list of discs?

Comment: What is 'multiple discounts'?  Just like the string?

Comment: redeemDisc function is too long to post in a comment. I have a list of discounts that are being shown in the postman response, the businessId holds the info for multiple discounts at the specific location. I just need to figure out a way so that when the `if (count > 1)` is triggered that it outputs the postman response that I just listed, which is currently does, and i need to also include the words 'multiple discounts'. With my current knowledge, I only know how to do one or the other but not both

Comment: yes 'multiple discounts' is just a string that i want to return alongside the other info currently being returned

Comment: Posted an answer.. That's what I would do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return an array where the first resolve is your string, the second one is the result from the request. You would get both at the same time.

```
    if (count > 1) {
    return Promise.all([Promise.resolve('multiple discounts'), this.redeemDisc(
        {
            //BusinessId: BusinessId,
            discountId: offer.id,
            userUuid: userUuid,
            code: code,
            locationId: locationId
        });
    )])
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this worked perfectly, I need to review promises, I didn't even consider this.

Comment: @mjm That's great! Would you mind marking this as the correct answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a string, and an object, but you can return the object with your message

```
return { ...redeemed, message: 'multiple discounts' }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!